# Making a function that inserts spaces depending on a variable length

Tags: ruby, string

So, I have a text file in which I've put:

```
'thing1'           => '"/path/to/a/file"'
#INSERTHERE
'longerthing2'     => '"/path/to/a/file"'
```

So my plan is to use `#gsub` to replace the `#INSERTHERE` with my variables value like:

```
File.read(filename).gsub(/#INSERTHERE/, "\'#{my_str_variable}\'         => \'\"/path/to/a/file\"\',\n#INSERTHERE")
```

Now to my predicament, is there a nice way I can make a function that puts in the correct number of spaces before `'=>'` depending on the length of `my_str_variable`? Or is there an even better way I just don't know about?

Comment: Not related to the question, but did you consider using Erb instead of gsub.

Comment: I would love to use ERB but these files I'm going to be gsub-ing are already "in use" and not something I'm creating (the files I'm creating im using ERB for) and I don't think it will solve my spacing issue? (I'm very new at this so bare with me :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a nice way I can make a function that puts in the correct number of spaces before '=>' depending on the length of my_str_variable?

There is. String#rjust or String#ljust, for example

```
def print_50(hash)

  hash.each do |k, v|
    puts "#{k} => #{v.rjust(50 - k.length - 4)}"
  end
end

h = {
  'some key' => 'some value',
  'some longer key' => 'another value'
}

print_50(h)
# >> some key =>                             some value
# >> some longer key =>                   another value
```

This method requires that you know the length to which to pad the string to. Inferring that from the file is a separate problem :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I know that the `=` will always appear on column 25 for instance, I'll play around with your example above and see if I can make something work.

Comment: Good answer, Sergio, but better if you'd also calculate the pad size, which is just a couple of lines of code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: but I do that, no? (padding a wrong thing, but doesn't matter)

Comment: I was just suggesting that you begin with something like `width = File.for_each(filename).find { |s| s[/^.*?=>/] }.size - 2`.

Comment: I just wanted to say @SergioTulentsev that this worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: So sorry! Didn't know I had to do that, my bad!

Comment: @ohmni: no worries :)